# Form validation keeps clearing fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate that text fields are not left blank using jQuery before trying to insert into MySQL database

So before I added the if condition to check that the fields are blank the insert worked fine and would fail if both were left blank but not one. I added the IF condition and it always clears the the fields and fails the save even if both text fields are filled out.

I have tried several different methods including the `.val()==""`, and the `.length==0`. Not sure why it keeps clearing all fields. Any help would be appreciated.

JavaScript file:

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
  //Check to see that no fields are left blank if one is all fields are cleared and save is failed from insert.php
  if ($("#name").val()==""){
    clearInputs();
    return false;
  }
  else if($("#comment").val()==""){
      clearInputs();
      return false;
  }
  else{
  //save the fields into an array and post to the result span then clear inputs 
  $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
     $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
     function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
  });
  clearInput();
  }
});

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});

function clearInput() {
  $("#name").val('');
  $("#comment").val('');
}
```

Comment: Your code *always* clears the fields.  Are you sure you didn't change something on the server side? Have you tried checking the actual contents of the POST transaction from the browser console? The code you've got should work - does it work still if you comment out the validation tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would clear both inputs if one is blank, instead of just popping up a message, but here's how you'd do it :

```
var inputs = $('#name, #comment'),
    form   = $("#myForm");

form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid = inputs.filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value).length;
    }).length === inputs.length; // all inputs have a value

    if (valid) {
        $.post( form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), function(info){ 
            $("#result").html(info); 
        });
    }else{
        inputs.val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't see where the OP code is really wrong (other than misspelling "clearInput").

Comment: @Pointy - Now that you've pointed it out, me neither! Just copied the code and rewrote most of it to be more logical, and did'nt really bother testing it for errors!

Comment: @adeneo I tried this but it is still failing to save if both fileds are filled out.

Answer (score 0):

I present this "answer" from a noob (me) perspective. I've used this style in some of my stuff. It is obviously not as elegant as that of adeneo.

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/B55J3/) is a fiddle.

HTML

```
<button id='clickme'>CLICK</button>
<div>Name:<input id='name' type='text'></div>
<div>Comment:<input id='comment' type='text'></div>
```

CSS

```
button {
    margin: 10px auto;
}
div {
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

JS

```
   $('#clickme').click(function(){
     var nametext = $('#name').val();
     var commenttext = $('#comment').val();
     if (nametext.length < 1 || commenttext.length < 1)
        {
         alert('Both fields need text');
         $(':input').val('');      
         }
        else
        {
         alert('Query sent');//ajax/post function here
         $(':input').val('');
         }
                                   });
```